# serving react on spring-mvc and jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, reactjs, spring-mvc

I have an application which is running on spring mvc and jsp. Recently i tried to add a new frontend to the application by using reactjs and communicate with the exciting application by REST.
I am thinking to serv this fronend as a static content on the servlet.
I made a new directory in web-inf called /html and to put a html file in it. it works and shows the html correctly. 
After i build my react application and put it at the same place. I need to put the java-script file with the other javascript file in application. 
The problem is now that it renders the html-file and find the javascriptfile but it doesnt render the react content and it doent show any error in the console. what am i doing wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">-->
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/inc/static/css/main.285dd4be.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/static/js/main.95b0c5db.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```